# + overlay specification broken?

Tags: beamer, overlays

Since a recent update, the +- overlay specification doesn't seem to work
anymore, for environments at least. I'm up to date with TexLive 2015
(beamer 36461 (3.36)). Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{On the first slide}
  Hello
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<only@+>{On the second slide}
  Goodbye
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I expect the second block to appear on the second slide (that's what it
used to do until recently) but the two blocks are on the same slide.

Comment: Your example doesn't use `<+->`.

Comment: @samcarter that would defeat the whole purpose of the + overlay specification

Comment: I get the same result with TL 2014.

Comment: @wilk sorry, I was confused because before the edit there had not been any overlay specs in the MWE. I will delete my comment

Comment: `<+(1)->` does work but `<+->` does not. Overlay specifications are tricky.... I don't see the point of trying to put `only@` in there.

Comment: thanks cfr, I'll use <only@+(1)-> for the time being. I need the only because sometimes I want to remove this block after a few slides. I'm positive that <only@+-> used to work. I just posted this example on the beamer mailing list.

Comment: You don't need only. You can just specify an end point `<+>` says only appear on `+`. `<+->` says only appear on `+` until the final slide. If you specify something different, it will stop appearing at that point.

Comment: Note that `<+->` will work *afterwards*. Or if something else has incremented the counter. See page 90.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for clarifying that. For some reason I put only@1 then only@+- today whereas I was previously using only@+ followed by only@+- and was surprised by the change. Also you're right about only@ not beeing needed: thanks to you I will save 5 key presses for each block from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour is the intended behaviour as documented in the manual (90):

> ```
> \begin{itemize}
> \item<+-> Apple
> \item<+-> Peach
> \item<+-> Plum
> \item<+-> Orange
> \end{itemize}
> ```
>
> The effect of the `+-`sign is the following: You can use it in any
>   overlay specification at any point where you would usually use a
>   number. If a `+-`sign is encountered, it is replaced by the current
>   value of the LaTeX counter `beamerpauses`, which is `1` at the beginning
>   of the frame. Then the counter is increased by 1, though it is only
>   increased once for every overlay specification, even if the
>   specification contains multiple `+-`signs (they are replaced by the same
>   number). In the above example, the first specification is replaced by
>   `<1->`. Then the second is replaced by `<2->` and so forth.

Comment: Also note this is unaltered between 2014 and 2014 :-)

Comment: @JosephWright [Indeed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279452/overlay-specification-broken/279456?noredirect=1#comment673204_279452), it is not even altered between 2014 and 2015, either.